# Search Filter for Comments

Tags: feature-request, search

Recently I was digging through old questions on DBA.SE in a quest to possibly revive and/or flag old questions that had received no TLC at all.

I was initially using the following search terms:

- `is:question`
- `answers:0`
- `votes:0`

Then I found out that some questions had at least received a comment, so they weren't totally without TLC.

I thought there might be an option to filter on questions that didn't have any TLC at all (without even a comment) and typed in `hascomment:no`.

That didn't seem to work so I went and had a look at the documentation. No luck, there doesn't seem to be an option to search for commented posts.

### Feature Request

Could we implement a `hascomment:[0-n]` option?

It probably would be as simple as adding an additional search predicate to the already existing search statement:

```
...AND p.CommentCount = 0
```

An example of a search on DBA.SE can be found via [Select Questions Without Upvotes, Answers or Comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/896477/select-questions-without-upvotes-answers-or-comments) (Stack Exchange Data Explorer).

Thank you for considering my proposal.

Comment: Another option would be looking for [Tumbleweeds](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed); of course, questions might have received votes/answers/comments *after* being awarded the badge. And the badge can be earned only once per user.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, that was worth considering, but having a nice search option `hascomment:[0-n]` would help search for questions/answers with or without comments in a broader sense. I guess `hascomment:[<|>][0-n]` might be even better.

Comment: Wanting this feature so I can scan unanswereds more precisely. Any info on existence?

Comment: I've elaborated on some potential use cases for such a search operator in [a feature request on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424143/208273).