# No comment filter

Tags: support, filtering

Is there any way that I can filter a question with no comments in it?
The *reason* I ask this is because sometimes it is frustrating to click on a question just to see that has been already answered as a comment.

If there is not a way to filter them, is it something that might be implemented in the future?

Comment: If a question has only been answered in a comment and it's not closed... **answer it!**  Comments are not answers! Fix the problem if you know the answer!

Comment: I thought of it. But it would feel as cheating. I am also reading [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196527/how-to-deal-with-answers-provided-as-a-comment) about what you suggested. Anyways, I think it would be much easier if I could just filter them.

Comment: How is it cheating? You're doing all the work unless you're literally copying the comment verbatim. Most comments are insufficient as answers. Take the time to flesh out a good answer in the context of the question and take the deserved credit. There's no cheating.

Comment: I guess you are right. Thank you!

Comment: If you really want to be nice, credit the person who wrote the comment.

Comment: Please also note that not all questions need answers. For example, if the question is caused by a typo or something similarly trivial, I vote to close as such and add a comment where the problem is. That way the question asker can fix their problem and the question gets closed, as it provides no value to the site. It will be automatically be deleted later. Adding an answer may interfere with the automatic deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a filter that lets you find questions without comments. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315296/334566) is a feature request for a comment filter, but it doesn't have an answer, and I don't expect that we'll get a comment filter any time soon. AFAIK, the internal search engine ignores comments, when I want to find old comments I use a `site:` search in Google.

I don't think there'd be a lot of utility for a search function that finds questions with zero comments. A question with no votes, no comments, and no answers is considered to be abandoned, and the system automatically deletes such questions, as Jeff Atwood explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/334566). If an unanswered question has comments, it will survive in the system a little longer.

If you're searching for juicy unanswered questions to answer, don't worry about the comments, even if the question appears to be answered in the comments. As Catija mentions, answers in comments are *not* proper answers, and you are improving the site by converting such comments into actual answers that people can vote on. Of course, if you use (or mention) other people's ideas in your answer you should give them some credit.

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer the actual question. Please read the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350747/158100) and the comments for the sensible thing to do.
While you can't "filter" on the site for questions with no comments, you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) to create and run a query to get a resultset that matches that filter.

Here is an [example of such query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1262367):

```sql
select top 1000 
       id [Post Link]
     , score
     , owneruserid [User Link]
from posts
where posttypeid = 1            -- Questions
and commentcount = 0            -- no comments
and closeddate is null          -- not closed
and answercount = 0             -- no answers
and score > 0                   -- positively scored
order by lastactivitydate desc  -- recently active
```

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday. The database schema is documented in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677) . If you're new to both SEDE and SQL do give the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) (never forget that the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created it) a try. There is a [SEDE chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) (you need the chat privilege) in case you have specific questions or need help with a query.

An alternative that I will not expand on here is using the advanced search of the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) but then you have to post process the result to remove the questions that  have a [comment_count](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) that is 0 (or maybe undefined, you never know with that JSON stuff). Don't forget to select comment_count to be added in the resultset as it is  not in there by default. I leave implementing this option as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That's very useful stuff. I will answer in this question if I ever make it work.